# In python, if a function doesn't have a return statement, what does it return?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given this example function:

```
def writeFile(listLine,fileName):
    '''put a list of str-line into a file named fileName'''
    with open(fileName,'a',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in listLine:
            f.writelines(line+'\r\n')
    return True
```

Does this `return True` statement do anything useful?

What's the difference between with it and without it? What would happen if there were no return function?

Comment: The function will always return `True` or raise an error, so the `return` isn't too useful here.

Comment: thank you ! and these your answers inspired me very much, i think i will ask more on stackoverflow and also do what i can.

Comment: FYI, `f.writelines(line+'\r\n')` happens to work, but it's incredibly wasteful; it's treating the argument as a sequence and writing out each element; `str` are iterables of their characters, so it's effectively `write`-ing each character individually (buffering saves you from actual system call overhead, but it's still a lot more work). `f.write(line+'\r\n')` would get the same result, and write as a block, not character by character.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If a function doesn't specify a return value, it returns `None`.

In an if/then conditional statement, `None` evaluates to False.  So in theory you could check the return value of this function for success/failure.  I say "in theory" because for the code in this question, the function does not catch or handle exceptions and may require additional hardening.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining that None is equal to False in terms of truth values.

Comment: i am sorry i am just a beginner,i will take care when the function needs handling exception.by the way ,i had tested that if i return nothing,it would return None.thanks

Answer (score 4):

The function always returns `None` if explicit `return` is not written.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `return True` at the end of the function, you can say stuff like: `a=writeFile(blah, blah)`

However, because it will always be `True`, it is completely pointless. It would be better to return True if the file was written correctly, etc.

If you don't explicitly return anything, the value will be `None`

Comment: I think it does, in fact, only return True if the file was written correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It does not make much sense to have a return statement on its own without being attributed or checked for a functionality.

Python returns None if nothing is returned. In your case you should probably return true if the opening file and writting is successful

Comment: thanks for your answer. i feel cool when i  can get help from thousand miles distance.