# PySpark's addPyFile method makes SparkContext None

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been trying to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274540/write-data-to-redis-from-pyspark). In PySpark shell, I get SparkContext as `sc`. But when I use `addPyFile` method, it makes the resulting SparkContext `None`:

```
>>> sc2 = sc.addPyFile("/home/ec2-user/redis.zip")
>>> sc2 is None
True
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You are trying to two different Spark contexts?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @eliasah: To add python redis module to different workers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is the [source code to pyspark's (v1.1.1) addPyFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.context-pysrc.html#SparkContext.addPyFile).  (The source links for 1.4.1 in the official pyspark docs are broken as I'm writing this)

It returns `None`, because there is no `return` statement.  See also:  [in python ,if a function doesn't have a return statement,what does it return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355083/in-python-if-a-function-doesnt-have-a-return-statement-what-does-it-return)

So, if you do `sc2 = sc.addPyFile("mymodule.py")`  of course `sc2` will be None because `.addPyFile()` does not return anything!

Instead, simply call `sc.addPyFile("mymodule.py")` and keep using `sc` as the `SparkContext`

```
def addPyFile(self, path): 
635          """ 
636          Add a .py or .zip dependency for all tasks to be executed on this 
637          SparkContext in the future.  The C{path} passed can be either a local 
638          file, a file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported filesystems), or an 
639          HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI. 
640          """ 
641          self.addFile(path) 
642          (dirname, filename) = os.path.split(path)  # dirname may be directory or HDFS/S3 prefix 
643   
644          if filename.endswith('.zip') or filename.endswith('.ZIP') or filename.endswith('.egg'): 
645              self._python_includes.append(filename) 
646              # for tests in local mode 
647              sys.path.append(os.path.join(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory(), filename))
```