# Call a child method inherit from parents inside another child method

Tags: python, parent-child

Method `Eval` in `Child` class inherits from `Parents` class; method `FirstOrder` in `Child` class calls method `Eval` in `Child` class. Codes:

```
class Parents:
     def Eval(self, x):
         return value, grad

class Child(Parents):
     def Eval(self, x):
         super(Child, self).Eval(x)

     def FirstOrder(self, x, x0):
         val, grad = self.Eval(x0)
         return val + grad * (x-x0)
```

and get:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I know an easy solution is to change `self.Eval(x0)` to `super(Child, self).Eval(x0)`. But I want to know why. From my understanding, calling `self.Eval(x0)` in `FirstOrder` will lead to the definition of method `Eval` in `Child` class. Since it is well-defined, then it calls `Eval` in `Parents` class.

Comment: you forgot to `return` from `Eval` in `Child`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Appreciate so fast a reply! I am new to python. So the `return` from `Eval` in `Child` cannot inherit from the `return` in `Parents` by `super`?

Comment: I just mean that `super(Child, self).Eval(x)` should have a `return` in front of it. You need to return the result of the `super` call, otherwise the child method will implicitly return `None`.

Comment: @Silentmovie "return" doesn't inherit. That *doesn't make any sense*. Inheritance applies to *attributes of objects*. In `Child.Eval`, you simply call `super(Child, self).Eval(x)`, which evalutates to whatever `value, grad` is, but you don't do anything with that return value, then the function terminates and returns `None` by default

Comment: This isn't really inheritance, it's more like delegating. @juanpa I'm pretty sure `Child.Eval` is redundant, right? and it'd be easier to inherit `Parents.Eval`?

Comment: Also, beside the point, but *UpperCamelCase* should be reserved for class names. For methods, use *snake_case*, i.e. `Parents.eval` and `Child.first_order`. Although note that `eval` is a builtin, so [you might want to use a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109333/4518341), like `eval_`.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for your follow-up and reminder the naming issue. `eval` is just an example but it is good to know that it is a builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `Child.Eval()`, so [it returns `None` implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15355150/4518341). You just need to add `return`:

```
def Eval(self, x):
     return super(Child, self).Eval(x)
```

---

However, this isn't inheritance, it's delegation. Using inheritance would mean simply not defining `Child.Eval()`. And in fact, that's the better option since `Child.Eval()` doesn't do anything additional.