# Python 3 map is returning a list of NoneType objects instead of the type I modified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working on getting a better grasp of Python 3 fundamentals, specifically objects and modifying them in the context of a list (for now).

I created a simple class called MyThing() that just has a number, letter, and instance method for incrementing the number. My goal with this program was to create a list of 3 "MyThings", and manipulate the list in various ways. To start, I iterated through the list (obj_list_1) and incremented each number using each object's instance method. Easy enough.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is perform the same operation in one line using the map function and lambda expressions (obj_list_2).

```
#!/usr/bin/env py
import copy

class MyThing:
    def __init__(self, letter='A', number=0):
        self.number = number
        self.letter = letter

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return("(letter={}, number={})".format(self.letter, self.number))
        
    def incr_number(self, incr=0):
        self.number += incr

# Test program to try different ways of manipulating lists
def main():
    obj1 = MyThing('A', 1)
    obj2 = MyThing('B', 2)
    obj3 = MyThing('C', 3)

    obj_list_1 = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
    obj_list_2 = copy.deepcopy(obj_list_1)    

    # Show the original list
    print("Original List: {}".format(obj_list_1))
    # output: [(letter=A, number=1), (letter=B, number=2), (letter=C, number=3)]

    # Standard iterating over a list and incrementing each object's number.
    for obj in obj_list_1:
        obj.incr_number(1)
    print("For loop over List, adding one to each number:\n{}".format(obj_list_1))
    # output: [(letter=A, number=2), (letter=B, number=3), (letter=C, number=4)] 

    # Try using map function with lambda
    obj_list_2 = list(map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1), obj_list_2))
    print("Using maps with incr_number instance method:\n{}".format(obj_list_2))
    # actual output: [None, None, None] <--- If I don't re-assign obj_list_2...it shows the proper sequence
    # expected output: [(letter=A, number=2), (letter=B, number=3), (letter=C, number=4)] 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I can't figure out is how to get map() to return the correct type, a list of "MyThing"s.

I understand that between Python 2 and Python 3, map changed to return an iterable instead of a list, so I made sure to cast the output. What I get is a list of 'None' objects.

What I noticed, though, is that if I don't re-assign obj_list_2, and instead just call `list(map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1), obj_list_2))`, then print obj_list_2 in the next line, the numbers get updated as I expect.

However, if I don't cast the map iterable and just do `map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1), obj_list_2)`, the following print statement shows the list as having not been updated. I read in some documentation that the map function is lazy and doesn't operate until it's use by something...so this makes sense.

Is there a way that I can get the output of `list(map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1), obj_list_2))` to actually return my list of objects?

Are there any other cool one-liner solutions for updating a list of objects with their instance methods that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Your lambda returns `x.incr_number(1)`, which is a method that returns nothing and any function that returns nothing explicitly, returns `None`, so you get a list of `None` values for each value in `obj_list_2`

Comment: This is very straightforward and there shouldn't be any mystery: `lambda x: x.incr_number(1)` returns whatever `x.incr_number(1)` evaluates to. Youd efined `MyThing.inc_number` to return `None`, hence you get all Nones.

Comment: More importantly, **you shouldnt use `map` for side effects**, *just use a for-loop*.

Comment: In the 'Standard' bit, you're modifying the objects in the list, not creating a new list with copies or anything of the sort. When you use `map`, you're constructing a new list, but you're not actually creating copies of the objects.

Comment: "Are there any other cool one-liner solutions for updating a list of objects with their instance methods that I'm not thinking of?" This is just the wrong mentality. Don't look for "cool one-liners", write idiomatic, readable, maintainable code. Sometimes, that might involve a one-liner. E.G. you want to use a mapping, filtering operation on some iterable to create a list? Bingo - use a list comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's only straightforward if it's understood, that's not very helpful (I agree with the content, as I already stated the same thing, but no need for the abrasiveness)

Comment: Related: [using map with None type functions](/q/69469563/4518341), [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](/q/5753597/4518341)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, thank you! That would explain why list comprehension wasn't working either. I do 95% C development professionally, so it wasn't immediately obvious to me that map didn't create copies of the objects I passed in, and lambdas are new-ish as well.

Comment: @DannyLovell a good rule of thumb is that python, and the built in API's, will *never* implicitly copy objects. This is definitely something that requires getting use to. One way to think of Python's semantics is that everything acts like a pointer to a generic PyObject, just that the pointers are automatically dereferenced (and you can't actually treat them like pointers, e g. No pointer arithmetic)

Comment: `map` is raretly needed in python as its list comprensions and generators are the preferred altenatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, your incr_number doesn't return anything. Change it to:

```
def incr_number(self, incr=0):
    self.number += incr
    return self
```

Comment: This is bad design. Mutator methods shouldn't return `self`. See [Why does append() always return None in Python?](/q/16641119/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea - not a comment on this particular piece of code, but method chaining is a thing. Its not necessarily a bad design.

Comment: @wjandrea that is fundamentally a decision about API design. If it is clearly documented, then it is one valid approach. Albeit, conventionally, that isn't the approach taken in Python, so the downside is that people who are used to Python might not expect it.

Comment: @ wjandrea - When your object itself is not iterable, you could and sometimes you should have your mutator returning self to facilitate comprehension, filter, map etc on a collection of your objects.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm aware of method chaining; for example it's commonly used in Pandas and NumPy, but they always return copies, never the original object as far as I know, and I'm not aware of any Python libraries that do.

Comment: @juanpa Point taken, maybe I should rephrase "bad" as "unconventional and possibly confusing", but then, I don't see any good reason to go with an unconventional design in this case.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Just use the for-loop. There's no advantage to using a `map` in this case.

---

Firstly:

- You're getting a list of `None`s because the mapped function returns `None`. That is, `MyThing.incr_number()` doesn't `return` anything, so [it returns `None` implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15355083/4518341).
- Fewer lines is not necessarily better. Two simple lines are often easier to read than one complex line.
- Notice that you're not creating a new list in the for-loop, you're only modifying the elements of the existing list.
- `list(map(lambda))` is longer and harder to read than a list comprehension:

  ```
  [x.incr_number(1) for x in obj_list_2]
  ```

  vs

  ```
  list(map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1), obj_list_2))
  ```

Now, take a look at [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/4518341) The top answer says **no**, it creates a list that never gets used. So there's your answer: just use the for-loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is clearly better, but here's another way anyway. Your `incr_number` doesn't return anything, or rather returns the default `None`. Which is a false value, so if you simply append `or x`, then you do get the modified value instead of the `None`

Change

```
list(map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1), obj_list_2))
```

to this:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.incr_number(1) or x, obj_list_2))
```